# JQuery Ajax request doesn't reach the server

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I wrote the following function that is supposed to send an AJAX POST request from the browser:

```
function addFormToDB(email, company, subject, text) { 
   var params = "email=" + email + "&company=" + company + "&subject=" + subject + "&text=" + text;
   $.ajax({
      url: 'http://127.0.0.1/submit',
      type: 'POST',
      data: '{"data":"' + params + '"}' ,
      xhrFields: {
         withCredentials: false
      },
      dataType: "jsonp",
      contentType: 'text/plain',
      success: function(data) {
         alert("success");
      },
      error: function(result) {
         alert("error");
      }
   });

}
```

In the server side (node.js + express) I have the following function that handles POST requests:

```
app.post('/submit', function(req, res) {
    console.log("enter function");
    var p = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        db.serialize(function() {
            db.run("INSERT INTO users VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)",
            [req.query['email'], req.query['company'], req.query['subject'], req.query['text']],
            function (err) {
                if (err) {
                    console.error(err);
                    reject();
                } else {
                    console.log("Transaction passed");
                    resolve();
                }
            });
        });
    });
    p.then(function(){
        res.status(200).send();
    }).catch(function() {
        res.status(400).send();
    })
});
```

I don't know why but when POST request is sent, nothing happens and the program doesn't enter the function of the POST request. The console doesn't say anything.

This is how the 'network' window looks:
[image]

I understand that 404 error code means that there is a problem with the routing. However, when the client code is this (no JQuery) it works fine:

```
var params = "email=" + email + "&company=" + company + "&subject=" + subject + "&text=" + text;
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.open("POST", "http://127.0.0.1:3000/submit?" + params, true);
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        console.log(xhttp.readyState + " " + xhttp.status);
        if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
            console.log("request " + params + " was sent to DB");
            alert("Thank You!");
        }
    };
    xhttp.send();
```

The path in both code snippets is the same: http://127.0.0.1/submit, so probably the problem is not with the path.

Do you know what is the problem?

Comment: Do you see anything on the `Network` tab of your debugger? Where do you call `addFormToDB()` from? Can we see the client HTML?

Comment: I edited the original post.

Comment: 404 means it can not find the path/file on the server.... so that where I would start to look

Comment: Looks like there is an issue with your routing since you are getting a 404. Have you tried hitting the endpoint with a REST client like postman?

Comment: @epascarello, I answered in the body of the post. When I use the same path without JQuery, it works fine.

Comment: @mrpotocnik, I also tried to launch a POST request using Postman. It also worked fine. It mean that the problem must be with the JS client code (in the JQuery version).

Comment: So what is the postman command you are running for it to work?

Comment: After a successful post with Postman you can click the code button and select javascript jquery ajax for generated code. Try using the code Postman generates. if it works you can compare between the two to find the potential error

Comment: code button? where is it?

Comment: to the right of the screen under the send and save buttons.

Comment: are tou talking about the Postman screen?

Comment: Why are you using a querystring on a post? Makes no sense. You can not have jsonp and a post! The Ajax and the plain JS example are not equivalent. Next why does one have a port and the other does not?

Comment: It's your content type. I don't believe you can post jsonp. (Just hit me)
remove the dataType parameter and change data: {}

Comment: in jquery you say: 'http://127.0.0.1/submit', in plain javascript you say "http://127.0.0.1:3000/submit?". It doesn't seem the same path to me... On what port is your server listening ?

Comment: @CrazySynthax yes, on the postman screen you should see the send and save buttons next to the url input. under the buttons you should see the word code in orange. click that link to get code generation options.

Answer (score 1):

Your issue here is the fact you are making aa JSONP call which is a GET request. You can not make a JSONP that is a POST. Looking at the request in the screenshot, you can see it is a GET.

```
dataType: "jsonp",   <-- changes the POST to a GET
```

JSONP works by sticking a `<script>` tag on the page so it is a GET. So in the end the Ajax and the plain JavaScript are not the same. Plain JavaScript would be to append a script tag to the page.

Answer (score 0):

What is it for?

```
var params = "email=" + email + "&company=" + company + "&subject=" + subject + "&text=" + text
...
data: '{"data":"' + params + '"}' ,
```

Just try it

```
data: { email: email, company: company, subject: subject, text: text }
```

in Node.js

```
req.param['email'] ... etc
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this (need to remove jsonp and data):
     function addFormToDB(email, company, subject, text) {

```
   $.ajax({
      url: 'http://127.0.0.1/submit',
      type: 'POST',
      data: {email: email, company: company, subject: subject} ,
      xhrFields: {
         withCredentials: false
      },
      success: function(data) {
         alert("success");
      },
      error: function(result) {
         alert("error");
     }
   });
```

}